# Getting typeError after adding layer to map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I go tthis type of error:
"Cannot read property 'closure_uid_521373967' of null".

This occures after i make source that contain no features yet.

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({

});
```

after that i make a Layer

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});
```

and then i init the map:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM({url:"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}) }), vectorLayer],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 3
    })
});
```

its seems to work fine in my home when it is simple as here , but when i try to make it work in my job , that the scanario is kind a bit more complicated , i lack that type of error that i mention before.

Comment: Your code looks OK, it can be something else.

Comment: Do you know where does this error can come from

Answer (score -1):

Please view this Snippet.

1. It is a good idea to separate layer definition from map instantiation. The latter makes things very convenient, but it makes things difficult for debugging.
2. With that in mind, I defined an OSM Layer and your Vector layer and added both to a map.
3. You don't need to use getElementById. You can simply supply the id of the div as the target of the map.
4. I'm not able to replicate your TypeError. My suspicion is that it came from the addition of the unnecessary getElementById, though.

Can you post a link to the code that's not working?

```js
// layers

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({

});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: vectorSource,
  })

});

var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [osmLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.6.0/ol.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id='map'>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Look at `url: vectorSource` - this cannot be right.

Comment: @ahocevar, I 100% agree with you that that should not be right, either. My intention in writing that code snippet that way was to minimise the number of changes I made so that we could test what was broken. He's trying to add a layer that does not have a source, which is also a problem, as you pointed out, but that's a different problem to the one he first mentioned. :D